# how to convert contour data set with x/y/z to 3d object

Tags: javascript, three.js, gis

I have set of data with x,y,z values of a contour. Kindly share your ideas how to make it use to draw it in 3D world webgl( i'm using three.js).

Comment: Contours are derived from 3D objects. If you can, try to talk to the person that made the contours to get their 3D object. Reconstructing a 3D object from contours is imperfect and non-unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of xyz coordinates and you just want to draw a contour as a line, you can use `THREE.Line` via something like this:

```
// CData is an array of [xyz] e.g. [[x0,y0,z0],[x1,y1,z1],...]
var G = new THREE.Geometry();
for (var i=0; i<CData.length;i+=1) {
    G.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(CData[i][0], CData[i][1], CData[i][2]));
}
G.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(CData[0][0], CData[0][1], CData[0][2]));
var Contour = new THREE.Line(G,new THREE.LineBasicMaterial());
```

Comment: one thing to mention is that x, y are the lat/lon not the proper cords.
eg.  x0=83.221754 x1=83.221665...etc.Then how to plot that small fractions.

Comment: Tsk! that's NOT xyz -- poorly played

Comment: I'm not sure of your rotation ordering, I leave the right choice as an exercise :)

    var G = new THREE.Geometry();
    var E = new THREE.Euler(0,0,,'ZYX');
    var R = radius_of_the_earth_in_the_right_units();
    for (var i=0; i<CData.length;i+=1) {
        E.set(0, THREE.Math.degToRad(CData[i][0]), THREE.Math.degToRad(CData[i][1]),'ZYX');
        G.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(R+CData[i][2],0,0).applyEuler(E));
    }
    G.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(CData[0][0], CData[0][1], CData[0][2]));
    var Contour = new THREE.Line(G,new THREE.LineBasicMaterial());